# Entity Framework Core: Scaffolding to Avoid Data Loss after to change Model/Entity

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, scaffolding

I had the following Model:

```
public class Promotion : BaseModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Market { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

It was created a Migration that was updated to the database. And some *promotions* was inserted on the database. But I needed to change the Promotion Model to this:

```
public class Promotion : BaseModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Market Market { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double Price { get; set; }
}

public class Market : BaseModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Adress { get; set; }
}
```

When I added a new Migration, I got the alert: "An operation was scaffolding that may result in the loss of data. Please review the migrations for accuracy."

That's the auto generated Up method of the new Migration:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "Market",
            table: "Promotions");

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<Guid>(
            name: "MarketId",
            table: "Promotions",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"));

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Markets",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                Adress = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                CreatedAt = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                DeletedAt = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                UpdatedAt = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Markets", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Promotions_MarketId",
            table: "Promotions",
            column: "MarketId");

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Promotions_Markets_MarketId",
            table: "Promotions",
            column: "MarketId",
            principalTable: "Markets",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    }
```

How can I update the database without lose data?

Comment: You have introduced a new entity (or owned entity) for the market. EF is not able to automatically resolve this as part of a migration. You will have to edit the migration manually to move the existing data to the new database layout.

Comment: I suspected that! But I don't know how to do it. I searched a lot, but I got no resolution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The safe way to upgrade production DB is to break it up in multiple steps:

1. Add new `Market` entity and attach it to `Promotion` entity `without dropping the existing column`
2. EF will generate you a migration - `CREATE TABLE` + `ADD FOREIGN KEY` statements
3. Make your code to update/insert/select new values from both `Market table` and `Market column` preferring `Market table`
4. You deploy this. Now, you've got both old column with data and new table out there, being in sync for the new data.
5. Write a data migration, which will copy old values from `Market column` to `Market table`. Run it. Now you've got your data moved to the new `Market table` and new data sitting in `Market table`
6. Update your code to stop using old `Market column`. Deploy the change
7. Remove `Market column` from you entity. EF will generate migration where column will be dropped. Deploy this. You now have your data and schema migrated

Comment: Where is the documentation on this? this is very interesting I didn't know

Comment: @I'mnewbie this is best practice not guide. This is best safe how to do that.